# How does one derive Runge Kutta methods from polynomial interpolation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, interpolation

In some numerical analysis classes, a neat way of deriving the Adams-Bashforth and Adams-Moulton methods is to approximate the function by a polynomial, and integrate the polynomial analytically over an interval. The integral of the Lagrange basis results in the familiar AB and AM coefficients.

On the other hand, I've only ever seen Runge-Kutta methods derived from Taylor series and/or algebraic considerations. I'm aware of a theorem from Wright (1970) that says that these methods are equivalent to collocation with polynomials, but I don't recall ever seeing a systematic derivation of RK methods from polynomial interpolation (and/or quadrature rules).

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to some resources for such derivations. I've been thinking about teaching my numerical analysis course using polynomial interpolation as the starting point for ODE and PDE methods.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't. The conditions for RK methods are highly non-linear. See these slides https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/ for a comprehensive summary for up to 4th order methods.

Comment: This isn't correct. See here:

https://na.math.kit.edu/marlis/download/meetings/08Oberwolfach/problems/gnibook-chap2.pdf

I guess this is also an answer to my question. I will see if anyone else weighs in before answering and closing.

Comment: Collocation methods can be written as Runge-Kutta methods, but not every RK method is a collocation method, especially not the explicit ones. It seemed that you claimed some kind of equivalence.

Comment: Hm. Fair point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer thanks to @LutzL. It turns out that many implicit RK methods can be connected to collocation methods, but not all RK methods are collocation methods.

For the ones that *are* connected to collocation methods, the RK coefficients (and therefore the order of accuracy) are tied to the quadrature rule used in the collocation method.

For more, see: https://na.math.kit.edu/marlis/download/meetings/08Oberwolfach/problems/gnibook-chap2.pdf

and

https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/

It also appears to be possible to generate many explicit RK methods from quadrature rules over a single interval, then replacing evaluations anywhere other than at the beginning of the interval with Forward Euler approximations. For more, see http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/478578_Chapter_3.pdf

Comment: The reference to the KIT is no longer available. Could you provide it somehow? Thank you

Comment: @link I can't find it, but these slides appear to cover the same thing: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~hiptmair/Seminars/GNI/slides/Landis.pdf